# How can I evaluate the accuracy loss of the converted ftlite model?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I trained a model based on the ssd-moblienet algorithm.And use the eval.py script to evaluate the mAP of the model.

I need to use this model on iOS, so I converted it to a tflite model and it works now.

I want to analyze the precision loss when converting a model by the mAP value before and after the model conversion. Is there a script similar to eval.py that can calculate the mAP value of the tflite model?

Or is there any other better way?

I am a newcomer using tensorflow, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any official script. You'll have a write a custom script which uses Tensorflow's metrics API found at `model/research/object_detection/metrics` passing the detections and groundtruth as arguments.

An example

```
# Append to $PYTHONPATH path to models/research and cocoapi/PythonAPI
from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
from object_detection.core import standard_fields
from object_detection.utils.label_map_util import create_categories_from_labelmap, get_label_map_dict

def evaluate_single_image(image_path, annotation_path, label_file):
    """ Evaluate mAP on image
    args:
        image_path: path to image
        annotation_path: path to groundtruth in Pascal VOC format .xml
        label_file: path to label_map.pbtxt
    """

    categories = create_categories_from_labelmap(label_file)
    label_map_dict = get_label_map_dict(label_file)
    coco_evaluator = coco_evaluation.CocoDetectionEvaluator(categories)
    image_name = os.path.basename(image_path).split('.')[0]

    # Read groundtruth (here, an XML file in Pascal VOC format)
    gt_boxes, gt_classes = voc_parser(annotation_path, label_map_dict)
    # Get the detection after post processing
    dt_boxes, dt_classes, dt_scores, num_det = postprocess_output(image_path)

    coco_evaluator.add_single_ground_truth_image_info(
        image_id=image_name,
        groundtruth_dict={
            standard_fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_boxes:
            np.array(gt_boxes),
            standard_fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_classes:
            np.array(gt_classes)
    })
    coco_evaluator.add_single_detected_image_info(
        image_id=image_name,
        detections_dict={
            standard_fields.DetectionResultFields.detection_boxes:
            dt_boxes,
            standard_fields.DetectionResultFields.detection_scores:
            dt_scores,
            standard_fields.DetectionResultFields.detection_classes:
            dt_classes
        })

    coco_evaluator.evaluate()
```

Here's a minimal [inference script](https://github.com/ChrystleMyrnaLobo/tflite-object-detection/blob/master/inference.py) with input preprocessing, output post-processing, ground-truth parsing and mAP evaluation for a single image.
For other metrics, refer `model/research/object_detection/metrics/*_test.py` for usage.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate your tflite model, you can use [TensorFlow Lite Python interpreter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#tensorflow_lite_python_interpreter_). 
This interprete predicts the result with tflite model which gives exact output.